# How to force update-alternatives to update jdk?

Tags: java, update-alternatives

I've got `java-6-openjdk` and `java-7-openjdk` running on Natty (11.04) on one machine and successfully toggle between them using

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work on a second machine of identical spec. The sym links in `/etc/alternatives` gets updated when i run `update-alternatives` but when i check `java -version` or `which java` it's always `java-6-openjdk`. I've been running java 7 using the entire path but this isn't ideal as I don't want to clutter build files with path names.

Any suggestions on what else I need to do to get update-alternatives to work ?

Comment: Do you tried to logout or test from a new terminal window?